# I want to extend Fragment and Activity in one class to use navigational drawer for an activity without changing my overall code

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

This is my one of my fragment activity among three. All I want to do is use functions from Activity class(ie use setContentView(), startActivity()etc). Please don't worry about the package name of the project which I deleted for some reasons. Thanks in advance!

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;




public class MessagesFragment extends Fragment {


    public MessagesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
    }

}
```

This is the activity which should be called after the button which is in the MessagesFragment is clicked

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class AddNewBiller extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addnewbiller);
    }
}
```

If the above ones are not clear then the following screenshots might help

(1) is the Messagesfragment Layout. In this when the user clicks the Add New Biller button they should be redirected to the (2) AddNewBiller Activity layout which is not a fragment.

Comment: Why would you need to extend both Fragment and Activity? This is impossible in Java and it signals that you want to do something very wrong!

Comment: Hi @npace All I want to do is click a button in this fragment which should redirect me to another activity. I know this is simple for most guys here but  I got stuck in this thing. please help

Comment: Screenshot-1  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7iegnn580czwods/Screenshot_061015_053554_PM.jpg?dl=0  Screenshot-2 https://www.dropbox.com/s/cy0k3qwsgim9rpt/Screenshot_061015_053635_PM.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Activity functions in fragment just use `getActivity()` for example `getActivity().startActivity(yourIntent)`

Comment: Thanks for the response! Where I should use getActivity()? In onCreate() or onCreateView()?  @rwojcik

Comment: It depends on how you attach fragment (if it is to a viewpager or something else). If you attach fragment simply to an Activity you should use `getActivity()` in any of these. Every method in fragment lifecycle should be albe to get an activity instance.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7iegnn580czwods/Screenshot_061015_053554_PM.jpg?dl=0 this is my fragment activity and it has a button called "AddNewBiller". When the user clicks the button the should be redirected to "AddNewBiller" Activity https://www.dropbox.com/s/7iegnn580czwods/Screenshot_061015_053554_PM.jpg?dl=0 . I couldn't do this because my fragment activity extends Fragment so im getting error while using this code  startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Dashboard.class)); which works fine when extending Activity instead of Fragment

Comment: Of course it won't work :)
change `startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Dashboard.class));` to `startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Dashboard.class));`

Comment: Thanks! startActivity() works fine but findViewById() method says it cannot resolve while extdending Fragment class instead of Activity. This is the last thing I have to solve.

Comment: Is this view in fragment or in an activity?

Comment: In Fragment! Fragment is completely new to me which is why I'm struggling

Comment: Then override onViewCreated() method and use `yourView = view.findViewById(R.id.your_view)`

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to answer based on what I have understood.See if it helps you.

1. Create an ActionbarActivity.
2. Create a layout for this activity and use android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout and a frame layout in it.
3. initialize the drawer layout and
4. Then you can create a fragment, create its layout and use the add method of fragment manager to attache the fragment it to the framelayout that you have created earlier.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7iegnn580czwods/Screenshot_061015_053554_PM.jpg?dl=0 this is my fragment activity and it has a button called "AddNewBiller". When the user clicks the button the should be redirected to "AddNewBiller" Activity https://www.dropbox.com/s/7iegnn580czwods/Screenshot_061015_053554_PM.jpg?dl=0 . I couldn't do this because my fragment activity extends Fragment so im getting error while using this code  startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Dashboard.class)); which works fine when extending Activity instead of Fragment

Comment: why are you not using actionbaractivity?? it will solve the purpose of having a navigational drawer as well

Comment: Do I need to use actionbaractivity insead of fragmet? If I did my methods inside oncreateview throws some errors mentioning it cannot be overided from the superclass. Thanks